# Mapbox gl js not letting me change the default colors of the MapboxDraw

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mapbox-gl-js

I am using Next and React and I can't seem to get `MapboxDraw` to change its default color scheme for the polygons.

I tried adding a style section to the draw object as its created but it does not actually change anything. I just want the default color of the polygons that are being draw to be different.

```js
    mapDraw.current = new MapboxDraw({
        displayControlsDefault: false,
        // userProperties: true,
        controls: {
            // point: true,
            polygon: true,
            trash: true,

        },
        defaultMode: 'none',
        style: [
            // ACTIVE (being drawn)
            // line stroke
            {
                "id": "gl-draw-line",
                "type": "line",
                "filter": ["all", ["==", "$type", "LineString"], ["!=", "mode", "static"]],
                "layout": {
                    "line-cap": "round",
                    "line-join": "round"
                },
                "paint": {
                    "line-color": "#D20C0C",
                    "line-dasharray": [0.2, 2],
                    "line-width": 2
                }
            },
            // polygon fill
            {
                "id": "gl-draw-polygon-fill",
                "type": "fill",
                "filter": ["all", ["==", "$type", "Polygon"], ["!=", "mode", "static"]],
                "paint": {
                    "fill-color": "#D20C0C",
                    "fill-outline-color": "#D20C0C",
                    "fill-opacity": 0.1
                }
            },
            // polygon mid points
            {
                'id': 'gl-draw-polygon-midpoint',
                'type': 'circle',
                'filter': ['all',
                    ['==', '$type', 'Point'],
                    ['==', 'meta', 'midpoint']],
                'paint': {
                    'circle-radius': 3,
                    'circle-color': '#fbb03b'
                }
            },
            // polygon outline stroke
            // This doesn't style the first edge of the polygon, which uses the line stroke styling instead
            {
                "id": "gl-draw-polygon-stroke-active",
                "type": "line",
                "filter": ["all", ["==", "$type", "Polygon"], ["!=", "mode", "static"]],
                "layout": {
                    "line-cap": "round",
                    "line-join": "round"
                },
                "paint": {
                    "line-color": "#D20C0C",
                    "line-dasharray": [0.2, 2],
                    "line-width": 2
                }
            },
            // vertex point halos
            {
                "id": "gl-draw-polygon-and-line-vertex-halo-active",
                "type": "circle",
                "filter": ["all", ["==", "meta", "vertex"], ["==", "$type", "Point"], ["!=", "mode", "static"]],
                "paint": {
                    "circle-radius": 5,
                    "circle-color": "#FFF"
                }
            },
            // vertex points
            {
                "id": "gl-draw-polygon-and-line-vertex-active",
                "type": "circle",
                "filter": ["all", ["==", "meta", "vertex"], ["==", "$type", "Point"], ["!=", "mode", "static"]],
                "paint": {
                    "circle-radius": 3,
                    "circle-color": "#D20C0C",
                }
            },

            // INACTIVE (static, already drawn)
            // line stroke
            {
                "id": "gl-draw-line-static",
                "type": "line",
                "filter": ["all", ["==", "$type", "LineString"], ["==", "mode", "static"]],
                "layout": {
                    "line-cap": "round",
                    "line-join": "round"
                },
                "paint": {
                    "line-color": "#000",
                    "line-width": 3
                }
            },
            // polygon fill
            {
                "id": "gl-draw-polygon-fill-static",
                "type": "fill",
                "filter": ["all", ["==", "$type", "Polygon"], ["==", "mode", "static"]],
                "paint": {
                    "fill-color": "#000",
                    "fill-outline-color": "#000",
                    "fill-opacity": 0.1
                }
            },
            // polygon outline
            {
                "id": "gl-draw-polygon-stroke-static",
                "type": "line",
                "filter": ["all", ["==", "$type", "Polygon"], ["==", "mode", "static"]],
                "layout": {
                    "line-cap": "round",
                    "line-join": "round"
                },
                "paint": {
                    "line-color": "#000",
                    "line-width": 3
                }
            }
        ]

    })
```